# initWithCoder in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert the below Objective C code to Swift. But struggling to do that. Could some swift experts help me please.

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@”http://www.apple.com”]
        self.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Try https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code to convert to swift. Just dump the objective C code and it converts it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I already tried this way, required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    } , but I'm unable to add other code inside this function.

Comment: It's definitely possible to add code inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    /* 
     * If you need call super.init(coder: coder)
     * make sure the father class implement this method manually
     * Otherwise use super.init() to instead
     */
    super.init(coder: coder) 

    let url: URL = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!
    let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
}
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: @atline Thanks for the suggestion, the answer has been improved